# IIS 7.5 Applications and Application Pool

Tags: iis

Here is my scenario. I have a website running under "AppPool1" and that works fine. I created a new application ("test") within that site and set that to use "AppPool2".

The problem is that http://mysite.com works, but http://mysite.com/test does not. I get a 500.19 error. If I switch it back to use "AppPool1" it works fine.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of an application pool? I thought you could do what I'm trying to accomplish? Are the app pools only supposed to be assigned to separate sites, not applications within a site?

I've tried recreating the app pools and assigning permissions to the directory of the application with no success.

Comment: You might wanna check the web.config file in the /test folder for error(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Make sure your root folder has the IIS AppPool\apppoolname permissions on it as well. Even if the application is in a different directory